# Probability of selecting more than x of a color given distribution?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

If you have 2000 candies distributed uniformly over 5 colors, what is the probability of getting more than 300 blue candies?

I was thinking of doing complementary counting, so

$$ 1-\sum_{i=0}^{300} {2000\choose{i}}\left(\frac 15\right)^{i}\left(\frac45\right)^{2000-i}$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: What you've written is certainly correct, but I wonder if it's the answer your instructor is looking for.  Have you been studying anything about approximating probabilities?  The central limit theorem, for instance?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, I felt like this answer was correct but perhaps not what the question is going for. What would be a way to approximate this using CLT?

Comment: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/179/