# Probability of selecting rocks based on an initial distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say you have a bag with 100 rocks in it, and you're told that 90 rocks are white, and 10 rocks are black.  However, after picking 10 rocks (without replacement), 6 are white, and 4 are black.  How do you calculate the probability of this happening, and in0turn, how could show that the initial statement you're told is "false" (or a statistical impossibility) based on a large enough sample of rocks selected from the bag.

Comment: hello! Welcome to MSE.  It would help if you add some more details to the question. 
Please mention whether you are looking for - probability of "90W and 10B" given "6W and 4B"? If not how do you quantify "falseness" (unless of course we consider the trivial case of more than 10 Black being picked)?

Comment: I think i'm looking for something similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072155/probability-of-selecting-more-than-x-of-a-color-given-distribution

I want to know what the probability of selecting 6W and 4B is, given the distribution is 90W and 10B.  

I'm not sure how to quantify 'falseness' exactly.  I was thinking something akin to a p value indicating that this event is very unlikely given the distribution--but i'm not sure what makes sense in this scenario

Comment: Do you have any initial distribution in mind of the 100 rocks? For example, do you have any prior as to claims of truth. For example: we expect 90W 10B out of 100 with probability $\binom{100}{10}0.5^90\times0.5^10$ as per some binomial distribution?

Comment: I think that is correct. Initial probability of selecting a white rock would be 90/100 and a black rock 10/100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $F$ to be the fact (event) that we selected $F_w$ white and $F_b$ black balls (6 white and 4 black balls in your case). Let $C$ be the claim that there are $C_w$ white and $C_b$ black balls (90 white and 10black balls in your case) we are picking from.

Now we apply bayes rule.
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(C|F)\cdot \mathbb{P}(F) &= \mathbb{P}(F|C)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C)\\
\mathbb{P}(C|F) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(F|C)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P} [F] }\\
\end{align*}
Now let $\{C_1,C_2,\dots\}$ all be competing claims of truth. Based on the initial distribution that you mentioned in your question, $\{\mathbb P [C_1],\mathbb P [C_2],\dots\}$ are all known. Let the set of all claims be $S$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(C|F) &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(F|C)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P} [F] }\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(F|C)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P}(F|C)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C)+\sum\limits_{C_i \in S\setminus{C}} \mathbb{P}(F|C_i)\cdot \mathbb{P}(C_i)}\tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

Now consider your question:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P [F | C] &= \frac{\binom{C_w}{F_w}\binom{C_b}{F_b}}{\binom{100}{F_w+F_b}} \\&= \frac{C_w!\cdot C_b!(F_w+F_b)!(100-(F_w+F_b))!}{100!\cdot F_w!\cdot (C_w-F_w)!\cdot F_b!\cdot (C_b-F_b)!}\tag{2}
\\&= \frac{\binom{90}{6}\binom{10}{4}}{\binom{100}{10}} \\&= \frac{(90!\cdot10!)^2}{100!\cdot 6!\cdot 84!\cdot 4!\cdot 6!}
\end{align*}

Given any claim, $C_i = \{C_w^i,C_b^i\}$, we can similarly compute $\mathbb P[F|C_i]$, based on (2)

---

Let us now assume some prior distribution over all competing claims $C_i$. One may choose a binomial distribution, for example, with initial probabilities $p_w = 0.9$, $p_b = 0.1$. In such a case, let us compute the probability of a claim $C \equiv \{C_w,C_b\}$ (where $C_w+C_b=100$).

Then $\mathbb P[C] = \binom{100}{C_w}p_w^{C_w}p_b^{C_b}\tag{3}$

---

Now, we have all the ingredients to compute the claim. We substitute equations (2) and (3) in equation (1), with the summation in the denominator of (1) taken over $C_w \in [F_w,100-F_b]$ (the other values have probability 0). Such a summation can be done numerically - I am not aware of a closed form solution.  Using these, you get $\mathbb P [C | F]$, which is the probability that you were told the truth.

Comment: accepted as answer--thank you!